# Using a different content type (image/png) for the portlet response in ResourceAwareController.handleResourceRequest method?

Tags: spring, image, spring-mvc, portlet, spring-portlet-mvc

I want to implement a dynamically generated image (a chart) through a portlet.
For this, I have extended a `org.springframework.web.portlet.mvc.ResourceAwareController` class and implemented the resource request handling in a `public ModelAndView handleResourceRequest (final ResourceRequest request, final ResourceResponse response)` method.

The code is similar to below:

```
   public ModelAndView handleResourceRequest (final ResourceRequest request, final ResourceResponse response) throws Exception{

        if some condition {
        try {
            response.reset ();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace ();
        }
        .
        .
        .

        final JFreeChart chart = createStatisticsChart (xyDataSet, period, stats.size ());
        final BufferedImage bi = chart.createBufferedImage (700, 430);

        if (null != bi) {
            response.setContentType ("image/png");
            OutputStream out;
            out = response.getPortletOutputStream ();

            final Iterator<ImageWriter> iter = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName ("png");
            if (iter.hasNext ()) {
                final ImageWriter writer = iter.next ();
                final ImageWriteParam iwp = writer.getDefaultWriteParam ();
                final MemoryCacheImageOutputStream mos = new MemoryCacheImageOutputStream (out);
                writer.setOutput (mos);
                final IIOImage image = new IIOImage (bi, null, null);
                writer.write (null, image, iwp);
            }
        } 
        .
        .
        .

        return null;
        }
        else some conditions {
            .
            .
            return new ModelAndView (returnPath)
        }
    }
```

Acccess to this is done using a portlet resource url.
But I always get a "text/html" output for this image, although in the above method, I set the content type of the portlet response to "image/png". Therefore I get a strange characters as the output, instead of the correct chart image.

�PNG   IHDR � �  rL�N.}IDATx���oh\wz��@)��R�>X��RJ��J��� ad�J � 2v�Z ���"��ٟ�DB���f��Ԥ��n��%, � S�fMvY7B�,!b� �l�+c�VX+ �6R����܌8 �F3Ҍ� ����s�Fg>��s��y& M�3v  ��� P�  ^��������`������˿��� � ӯ�ʯ����t���499y�� z�5�#���������<���j�^}�
_H�W�~� �}�_ߣj~��{�(x���� _L��.............

Please let me know how can I change the content type of the Portlet response to "image/png" content type correctly when we use resource URLs. (Please note that for some of the conditions, above method should return "text/html")

**Update:**
I get an encoded string for the image data, instead of the expected raw bytes of image data. It turns out when a portlet calls a servlet, the outputStream is not actually a normal OutputStream. response.getOutputStream() returns an object of org.apache.pluto.container.util.PrintWriterServletOutputStream, which actually uses a writer which encodes whatever data we write using this OutputStream. Therefore eventhough I expected raw bytes from image, I get the encoded string of the image bytes.

**New Question:**
Is it possible to override the write method of PrintWriterServletOutputStream to write raw bytes, instead of an encoded string?

Comment: You're getting a PNG back - you can see the PNG signature (the "PNG IHDR" string) at the beginning of your output.  I question though a method that sometimes returns a PNG and sometimes returns HTML.  That seems a bit overloaded.  At a guess your HTML is expecting HTML and tries to display the PNG as HTML.

Comment: @stdunbar Please see the updated question. The output is not exactly the PNG image, it is encoded string.